# ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) when trying to deploy mern app to heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, deployment

I am a beginner when it comes to `NodeJs` and I'm following a `MERN` stack youtube tutorial recently posted by [brad traversy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UXjMo25Nnvc&t=2375s). I have completed the tutorial and have gotten to the deployment section of the application but when following the tutorial I get the following error. I don't really understand where this issue is coming from so I attached the server.js file and package.json file as well as the actual Heroku error in the terminal.

```
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 21.14 KiB | 10.57 MiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 16.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 16.14.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 8.3.1
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        
remote:        added 226 packages, and audited 227 packages in 13s
remote:
remote:        24 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:        
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running heroku-postbuild
remote:        
remote:        > mern-stack-2022@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild
remote:        > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix frontend && npm run build --prefix frontend
remote:
remote: npm ERR! code ENOENT
remote: npm ERR! syscall open
remote: npm ERR! path /tmp/build_b752602d/frontend/package.json
remote: npm ERR! errno -2
remote: npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_b752602d/frontend/package.json'
remote: npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
remote: npm ERR! enoent
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.esoMP/_logs/2022-02-22T21_55_05_519Z-debug-0.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry-this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 377a2a25a1b56c226e11f9f9c45f371cc85adcea
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 377a2a25a1b56c226e11f9f9c45f371cc85adcea
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push Heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to mern-tutorial-2022.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/mern-tutorial-2022.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/mern-tutorial-2022.git'
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "mern-stack-2022",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node backend/server.js",
    "server": "nodemon backend/server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix frontend",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix frontend && npm run build --prefix frontend"
  },
  "author": "Ope Afolabi",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^7.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

server.js

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const { errorHandler } = require('./middleware/errorMiddleware')
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config()
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const connectDB = require('./config/db')

connectDB()

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.json(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })))

app.use('/api/goals', require('./routes/goalRoutes'))
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/userRoutes'))

// Serve frontend
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/build')))

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'))
    })
} else {
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('Please set to production')
    })
}

app.use(errorHandler)
 
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`))
```

Comment: Do you have a `frontend/` directory? What does it contain?

Comment: I took a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/Mk5NAch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems clear to give you the reply:

> We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with
> version 377a2a25a1b56c226e11f9f9c45f371cc85adcea remote:  ! at least
> twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code
> from a different branch.

That string is a hash of your bundle, the error is telling you that you already deployed the same bundle.
My guess is that you pushed the same bundle from the develop branch instead of the master before.
I suggest you make a change, create a new release and push from the master branch this time.

This message:

```
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
```

tells you how to deploy from a different branch during development.

Answer (score 0):

instead of pushing directly to the Heroku create a repository in Github then go to the Heroku dashboard create the new app after that in the deploy tab, you can connect your GitHub repo to Heroku and you can also enable Auto to deploy.

[image]